# Android Layout with 2 TextViews on left and CheckBox on right has text over checkbox

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to have a complex ListView that has a Title and Description on the Left side and a Checkbox on the right side. I am doing this, but the text on the left is going over the Checkbox on the right.

How can I prevent that?

My layout code currently looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dip"
android:paddingBottom="10dip"
android:paddingLeft="15dip">
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/list_checkbox" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:checked="false"
    />   
<TextView
    android:text="Some Title"
    android:id="@+id/list_complex_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_checkbox"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    />    
<TextView
    android:text="Some long description Some long description Some long description Some long description Some long description."
    android:id="@+id/list_complex_caption"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#98AFC7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_complex_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately I'm new to the site and need more points to post image :(

If possible, I would like to center the Checkbox vertically as well.

Any layout experts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do more. . 
As per your Layout Code, Just give Left margin to the TextView that is going over the Checkbox.
It Will solve your problem.
I have done it.

Comment: If you set left margin to TextView how it can solve this problem ? it will keep space left side but it will not solve this issue.TextView is wrapping on checkbox right side

Comment: @Dhrmendra : if u give the Left margin to the TextView as same as the width of the check box, it will not going over on checkbox. And the issue of this question is that the text should not be going over the checkbox.

Comment: Problem is but the text on the left is going over the Checkbox on the right. he has mentioned in his question.Check it again.

Comment: I think user914453 has solve the problem by my answer so its over now. Thanks For the Reply.

Answer (score 2):

Write a statement

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_checkbox"
```

In your description textview so that it will be not goes over to checkbox

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Is there a way for me to vertically center that Checkbox?

Comment: I was able to center it vertically with:
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Comment: Write a line  android:layout_centerVertical="true" in your checkBox